# When I setMinimumHeight, what units am I using?

Tags: android, pixel, android-view

I want to set the size of an ImageView manually. The ImageView has a function [setMinimumHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMinimumHeight%28int%29), as to all views. What units am I telling the ImageView to place it in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting and setting the size in pixels. When the `minWidth` attribute is inflated from XML it's translated into a pixel measurement from its dimension:

from View.java:

```
case R.styleable.View_minWidth:
    mMinWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, 0);
```

Comment: @GMsoF : You can convert your dip value to pixels and use that when calling `#setMinimumHeight(int)`. Easiest way is probably to use the method `TypedValue#applyDimension(int, float, DisplayMetrics)` to convert it to pixels.